# keystore file's character length seems really small to be a wallet/key

Tags: wallets, keystore

Apologies, new to Ethereum, but I have read a bit and searched.
wc -c of my keystore file is only 491 characters and I don't see anything that looks like a private key block.

Could this possibly be the only thing I need to back up in case of loss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've several keystore files that are working all of them are 491 bytes.

They are very similar to the file that appears in this [wiki](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens):

```
{"address":"c2d7cf95645d33006175b78989035c7c9061d3f9",
  "crypto":{
    "cipher":"aes-128-ctr",
    "ciphertext":"0f6d343b2a34fe571639235fc16250823c6fe3bc30525d98c41dfdf21a97aedb",
    "cipherparams":{
      "iv":"cabce7fb34e4881870a2419b93f6c796"
    },
    "kdf":"scrypt",
    "kdfparams"{
      "dklen":32,
      "n":262144,
      "p":1,
      "r":8,
      "salt":"1af9c4a44cf45fe6fb03dcc126fa56cb0f9e81463683dd6493fb4dc76edddd51"
    },
    "mac":"5cf4012fffd1fbe41b122386122350c3825a709619224961a16e908c2a366aa6"
  },
  "id":"eddd71dd-7ad6-4cd3-bc1a-11022f7db76c",
  "version":3
}
```

The private key is encrypted in the "ciphertext" field inside "crypto" section.

If you want to access the private key you can use a library like [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet).